# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exc-bad-access, viewdidload, super

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    @try {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"taskListSegue"])
        {   
            MindMapInformationViewController_iPhone *taskListContentController = [segue destinationViewController];  
            int selectedIndexPath = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

            MindMap *newMindMap;
            newMindMap = [mindmaps objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath];        
            FileManager *fileManager = [[[FileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
            [fileManager readFile:newMindMap.pathToMindmapAtDevice parsing:YES];

            NSMutableArray *taskArray = [fileManager getArray];
            [taskListContentController setTasksOfSelectedMindmap:taskArray];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
}

-(void)setTasksOfSelectedMindmap:(NSMutableArray *)tasks {
    @try {
        [self initComponents];
        if (tasks != nil) {
            taskArray = tasks;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }

}

-(void)initComponents {
    @try {
        taskArray = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init];

        taskName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        taskOwner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    @try {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        int i = 0;
        for (MindMapTask *newTask in taskArray) {
            if (newTask.taskOwner == nil) {
                newTask.taskOwner = @"Keine Angabe";
            }
            [taskName addObject:newTask.taskTitle];
            [taskOwner addObject:newTask.taskOwner];

            i++;
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception - %@", exception);
    }
}
```

Why I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? The producer of this exception seems to be `[super viewDidLoad]; ...`

Can anyone help me ? :)

EDIT: Changed the code a bit.. hope its understandable

You can see, that i moved the definiton of the arrays into an own method. I also added a method to make sure, that the taskTitle isn't nil (in an other class).

Comment: if you run the Analyzer you'll see quite a few memory leak issues. Fix those first and try again.

Comment: i ran the analyzer, there aren't memoryleaks ;)

Comment: To be sure where the exception is, try putting [super viewDidLoad]; and the rest of the code in separate try/catch blocks. If the problem is in the parent code, when can't help you just looking at this code. If the problem is in this code, try verifying that taskArray and newTask.taskTitle are not nil.

Comment: set up NSZombieEnabled for your executable in Xcode to fix memory leak

Comment: have you profiled with the Leaks Instrument?

Comment: yes, instruments can't find any leak.

Comment: Leaks don't cause crashes, and this code does not leak if the questioner is using ARC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting

```
[super viewDidLoad];
```

As the first statement.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `newTask.taskTitle` is not NULL.

Comment: i implemented this, but this don't changes the error/exception

Comment: if (newTask.taskOwner == nil || newTask.taskTitle == nil) {
                newTask.taskOwner = @"Keine Angabe";
                newTask.taskTitle = @"Keine Angabe";
            }

so newTask.taskTitle can't be nil anymore

Answer (score 0):

Is taskArray still a valid object? Where is it defined? Was it maybe autoreleased?

When you add a breakpoint at the beginning of the function, are all objects valid? (You can check that in the debugging console, with "po", e.g. "po taskArray")

Comment: I'll try this at friday, when I'll be in front of the computer in my office :)